# Unit testing angular service with dependencies

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I have the following Jasmine unit test:

```
describe('myService', function () {
    var myService, $q;

    // Instantiate the app
    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function (_myService_, fileSystemService, $q) {
        myService = _myService_;
        spyOn(fileSystemService, 'listFiles').and.callFake(function () {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve('mockresult');
            return deferred.promise;
        });
    }));

    it('checks the number of outbound files', inject(function ($rootScope) {
        var result;
        myService.sendOutboundFiles2().then(function (res) {
            result = res;
        });
        $rootScope.$digest();
        expect(result).toBe('mockresult');
    }));
});
```

Which tests this very simple service function:

```
sendOutboundFiles2() {
     return fileSystemService.listFiles('Cached/Outbound').then(function(outfiles) {
         return outfiles;
     })
}
```

However when the test runs, it fails with a spurious `Error: Unexpected request: GET blah\blah\blah.html No more request expected at $httpBackend` error but i have no idea why as neither this test nor the service dependencies do anything with $httpBackend.

**MORE INFO**

If i comment out my existing controller tests, I get this error: 
[image: service test only]

If i add my controller tests back in, I get this error:
[image]

So depending on which tests i add or remove, the HTML file in the `GET` error changes. But all the controller tests run fine. WTF?!?!?!!??!?!!?

Comment: That sounds like an error caused by Angular trying to fetch the template for a directive/component. Are you doing any manual compilation inside your services, or running other tests which do?

Comment: I have taken out my other unit tests, but i still get the error. Although strangely it's now referencing a different .html file in the `GET` error.

Comment: Do you have any other services that compile directives when they are instantiated (i.e. in the constructor, or a method called from it)? Or ones that make `$http` requests in the constructor? Can you try making the smallest possible Angular module with just the bare minimum you need and then try testing that? Chances are something you don't expect and aren't trying to test is making a HTTP request.

Comment: I've stripped the service back as far as i can to do this test. Still get the same error. Put all my controller unit tests back, they all work fine. It's just the service test that's failing.

Comment: Maybe show the full code for your `myService` then? Have you confirmed that if you remove this test and add back in all the controller tests, that they work fine? Sometimes other tests can bleed through and cause an unrelated test to fail, because they do something async or whatever.

Comment: Somewhere you are making a $http.get request, normally when you see *.html, that is a directive trying to get it's template, yet I don't see any directive in your test or even a route that would go a *.html file, look for that blah.html file in your app.. is it it a template or something?

Comment: I have added some more information to the question (including some screenshots)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by Ionic's keen prefetching of all templates into a cache. No idea why this doesn't occur when testing a controller though. The problem only appears when i was testing a service. Any way, I found this thread: [Karma test breaks after using ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/212#issuecomment-69974072) and the relevant fix is to add this snippets before injecting any dependencies:

```
  beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
    $provide.value('$ionicTemplateCache', function(){} );
  }));
```

This stubs out the $ionicTemplateCache and prevents it from trying to preload all ui-router templates into the Ionic cache.